# Unable to Retrieve ArcGIS Roles from ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: python, arcgis

Using Notebook, I'm unable to list all the roles in the portal. When I tried I get this output which I'm aware but forgot to change this type to text. Appreciate your response in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing parenthesis:

- [image]
- [image]

See [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.RoleManager.all) for the RoleManager's `.all()` method.